# ExtJS 4 buttons in grid to edit, delete a row. open edit-form in a new tab

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Basically my problem is splited into 2 parts. There are examples in the ExtJS 4 examples for extending a grid. but they are not working :( I'm using ExtJS 4 in the new recommended mvc application pattern.

1. Add a first column into a grid with buttons for editing and deleting
2. The grid is the first tab of a tabpanel. If the edit button is pressed a new tab should be created and bound to the store.
3. A new button should open a tab with a empty form bound to a store

Has anyone experiences with this? Any working code examples? I appreciate your help! Thx!

Comment: "There are examples in the ExtJS 4 examples for extending a grid. but they are not working" - Which examples you found to be not working? Have you tried creating some code and facing any errors in that? Please post that here if there are any issues which are unresolved in your code.

Comment: It shows how to extend the grid with expandable icons and checkboxes for multi select. (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html) But it doesn't show how to implement real buttons or toolbars in a row. I'd need a model to handle clicks on them as well. Adding a toolbar or button as a column doesn't work. No errors but the screen gets screwed. So far I solved the problem for me. Selecting a row activates buttons in a tbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a way to add buttons (or more correctly images).

So you need add new column with xtype: 'actioncolumn', and describe each button (image) as item.

E.g.:

```
...
columns: [
            {
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'registrant_name',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 40,
                items: [{
                    icon: 'path_to_img',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colindex) {
                        alert('click!');
                    }
                }]
            }
        ],
...
```

Also link on doc page:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action